# Booting 2 ElasticSearch nodes on the same machine: RemoteTransportException: failed to send join request to master

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to boot up 2 ES nodes on the same machine. I have copied my ES directory and trying to start a new node from the copied directory and I am getting above exception.

I have updated `node.name`, `https.port` in the `elasticsearch.yml` in the copied directory.

This is the exact error:

> [2018-12-30T01:23:31,692][INFO ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [node-2] failed to send join request to master [{W_D20zp}{W_D20zpzT52ZKv0FJhKvtQ}{dSd_YBoZTfSjnV908G6c5A}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}{ml.machine_memory=17179869184, ml.max_open_jobs=20, xpack.installed=true, ml.enabled=true}], reason [RemoteTransportException[[W_D20zp][127.0.0.1:9300][internal:discovery/zen/join]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[can't add node {node-2}{W_D20zpzT52ZKv0FJhKvtQ}{kdw6N1WTS4O3aGbVFY8Zew}{10.0.0.194}{10.0.0.194:9300}{ml.machine_memory=17179869184, ml.max_open_jobs=20, xpack.installed=true, ml.enabled=true}, found existing node {W_D20zp}{W_D20zpzT52ZKv0FJhKvtQ}{dSd_YBoZTfSjnV908G6c5A}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}{ml.machine_memory=17179869184, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20, ml.enabled=true} with the same id but is a different node instance]; ]

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this problem and spent a few hours trying to resolve this so sharing here for others' reference.

As mentioned in https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/21405, you have to delete the `nodes` directory when you copy the ES directory to start a new node.

`nodes` directory is located either in `{ES_HOME}/data/nodes` or `/var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes`.

HTH!